# How could I know if I'm developing a c++/cx or c++/WinRT UWP application?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-cx, c++-winrt

I'm creating a c++ UWP application and I want this app to be c++/WinRT because I read that c++/cx is not supported anymore.
And this is how I created my application.
VS 2017 -> File -> New -> Project... -> Visual C++ -> Windows Universal -> Blank App (Universal Windows)
I'm sorry for this basic question but I couldn't find out if my app is a c++/WinRT or not.

Comment: Both C++/CX and C++/WinRT are supported. That said, some newer compiler features (like two-phase name lookup) are not compatible with the C++/CX extensions. The default C++ *Blank App* is using C++/CX which you can see because of the use of ``ref class``.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++/CX and C++/WinRT do not generate different application types. Even if C++/CX weren't supported anymore (it still is), an application compiled using C++/CX would still continue to run. C++/CX is purely a language-level compiler setting, that generates native code just like C++/WinRT.

You opt in to C++/CX by setting the [/ZW (Windows Runtime Compilation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zw-windows-runtime-compilation) compiler option. If that compiler option isn't present, you aren't using C++/CX. The *Blank App (C++/WinRT)* project template (available after installing the [C++/WinRT Visual Studio extension](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt/vsix)) doesn't set the /ZW compiler option. The *Blank App (Windows Universal)*, on the other hand, does set the /ZW compiler option.

Comment: Most of the UWP templates that come with Visual Studio are set up to use the C++/CX extensions (i.e. ``/ZW``). You can install C++/WinRT project and item templates from [Visual Studio Marketplace](https://aka.ms/cppwinrt/vsix). I also have C++/WinRT variants of basic Direct3D projects on [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates).

Comment: @chu: I didn't realize (or forgot), that there are Universal Windows project templates for C++/CX. Updated the answer to include information on both *Blank App* project templates.